# upgrade requires 525M free disk space on /boot while boot is only 230M in total there are also dependencies with previous kernels

Tags: package-management, kernel, dependencies

I was having problems installing the latest kernel due to lack of free space in the /boot partition. Finally I managed to force delete the old kernel files, but when I tried sudo apt-get -f install it installed all previous kernels and one of them could not finish installing as it filled all the /boot partition again. I deleted the kernels again and now I have dependency issues with most of those kernels. Also, when I attempt to upgrade through the GUI it says that it it requires 525M to upgrade and /boot only has 230M available, I assume the solution is making the /boot bigger but I do not know how to do it.
To clarify:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-33-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-37-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.19.0-37-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manner in which you managed to "force delete the old kernel files" was probably not the best method for opening up some space on your /boot partition. There is a guide [at this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) to help free up some space.

For the 6 packages listed in your error message, remove them one-by-one, using the commands

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-33-generic
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-extra-3.19.0-37-generic
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```